# Magento 2 _theme.less media queries

Tags: magento, less, themes, magento2, magento-2.0

is there any trick adding styles to _theme.less so they are only in processed styles-m.css or styles-l.css

Normally the styles from _theme.less is processed in both.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, code wrapped in

`& when (@media-common =true) {
...
}`

will only be added once

Answer (score 0):

From how i understood it, styles-m.css would have both desktop and mobile styling while styles-l.css would have desktop only. I have shared a link to a question related to yours see [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155539/magento-2-style-m-css-vs-style-l-css/155542#155542).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers. Thanks!

Comment: @GhostCat That would be okay but it would put me in a position of duplicating the answer which is already existing on the other post. Which is also being avoided here on stackoverflow. But i do agree with the link based answers :).